# Limit of $a_n$ is -$2$ then consider $\sum a_n ^{-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> If the limit of $a_n$ is -$2$ then consider  the infinite series $\sum a_n ^{-n}$. Does this converge or diverge?

I thought that because of the exponent, the root test will be a good approach. Consider:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n^{-n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{a_n}= -\frac{1}{2}<1$$ so the limit converges. Am I correct in saying this?

---

Edit: a condittion for the root test is that $a_n>0$ this is clearly not the case, my proof fails.

Comment: Not quite.  Be careful about signs.

Comment: oh yeah, a condition on the root test is that $a_n >0$

Comment: Consider $\sum a_n^{-n}\le\sum |a_n|^{-n}$ and apply root test.

Comment: Or the alternating series test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$a_n\sim \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

which clearly converges by geometric series.

As an alternative consider the $\sum |a_n|$ and apply root test if you want use that.

Comment: Oh yeah is converges absolutely, so it converges.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Yes and indeed I think that th eproper way to prove that is to consider the absolute convergence.